# Visual Studio see html changes without rebuilding code

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

Working with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019.

I have a project ASP.NET core (but I dont think it is related to core)

When I run the project via IIS Express\project button

[image]

When I modify a file (cshtml) "html file" in Core project and click F5/Ctrl+F5 I dont see the changes applied. I need to stop the project and run the project again to see html changes. I understand when modifying the source code I need to rebuild and rerun.

Is there a configuration in VS I need to set so that html changes get reflected when I refresh the page, would save me some much time to see the changes without rebuilding/rerunning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can install **NuGet Package**

**Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation**

first, and in ConfigureServices(), add:

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

then you can just refresh the cshtml to see the changes.